# PROBLEMA CON EL ARGV EN C

Tags: c, linux, bash

Hola hice este código para identificar números primos en c,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int numero=atoi(argv[1]);
    int i=1,division, divisible=0;
    while (i<=numero){
        division= numero%i;
        divisible++;
        i++;
    }
    if(divisible==2){
        printf ("El numero %d es primo",numero);
    }
    else{
        printf ("El numero %d no es primo",numero);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al ejecutarlo con script de bash me sale el error de

```
File "primo.c", line 5
    int main (int argc, char const *argv[]){
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Nose en que estoy fallando, gracias por la ayuda...

Comment: No tienes que ejecutarlo con bash, tienes que compilarlo. Prueba con `gcc primo.c && ./a.out`.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien ha dicho @Pablochaches en el comentario, el código escrito en C (así como en C++ y otros lenguajes) debe compilarse antes de poder ser ejecutado. En comparación a otros lengaujes como pueden ser Python o el propio bash en el que con indicar qué intérprete usar es suficiente.

Entiendo que estás en un sistema linux, la siguiente orden te permitirá compilar un fichero escrito en C (nombre_fichero_a_compilar.c) y dejará el ejecutable en el fichero (nombre_ejecutable_compilado), deberías cambiar el nombre de estos ficheros por los tuyos:

```
gcc nombre_fichero_a_compilar.c -o nombre_ejecutable_compilado
```

Una vez hayas resuleto posibles errores que tengas en el código y se haya compilado puedes ejecutar el programa con la orden:

```
./nombre_ejecutable_compilado
```

Es importante el "./" (que en bash indica el directorio actual) para que este sepa que debe ejecutar el fichero "nombre_ejecutable_compilado" que se encuentra en el directorio actual y no realize una búsqueda del ejecutable por el sistema.

¡Espero que te sirva!